# Equation of the line given the tangent lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Tangent lines to

> $x^2+y^2-18x-2y+48=0$

at points where $x = 4$

How do you solve this kind of problem?
P.S. the answer to this problem is

> $y = 5/3 x - 8/3$

and

> $y = - 5/3 x + 14/3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take differentiation w.r.t. $x$ both sides,
$$
2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}-18-2\frac{dy}{dx}+0=0
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{9-x}{y-1}
$$
At $x=4$ equation $(x^2+y^2-18x-2y+48=0)$ becomes ,
$$
16+y^2-72-2y+48=0
$$
$$
y^2-2y-8=0
$$
This gives $y=-2$ or $y=4$  so,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{9-x}{y-1}=>(\frac{dy}{dx})_{x=4,y=-2}=\frac{-5}{3}
$$
and
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{9-x}{y-1}=>(\frac{dy}{dx})_{x=4,y=4}=\frac{5}{3}
$$
These two slopes at $(4,-2)$ and $(4,4)$ gives two lines as,

**Line 1:**
$$
\frac{-5}{3}=\frac{y+2}{x-4}
$$
On rearranging,
$$
y = \frac{-5}{3} x + \frac{14}{3}
$$
**Line 2:**
$$
\frac{5}{3}=\frac{y-4}{x-4}
$$
On rearranging,
$$
y = \frac{5}{3} x - \frac{8}{3}
$$